# .NET webservice pdb deployed still no line numbers

Tags: asp.net, debugging, msbuild, pdb-files, aspnet-merge

If anyone can help this one I would appreciate it, I have searched and built for a while.

1. website project
2. build using CCNET
3. Built using msbuild and config DebugType=pdbonly
4. Merge all files into single assembly using aspnet_merge and -a -debug
5. pdb is in same directory as .dll
6. debug=true in web.config
7. No impersonation going on
8. Framework 4.0 (still checked, no reference to deployment)
9. Captured via ex.ToString()

Sample stack trace

> System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid.
>      at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(Object Value)
>      at UserControls_OpportunityManagement.GetReferralMethodIDByDialedNbr(String DialedNumber)

Comment: Point 9 makes me worry. How shall we answer this without knowledge about the "internal assembly"?

Comment: Good point, I changed the way we are logging so now I am logging ex.ToString directly and not using our logger. In this case it is a user control of a web site, I am not sure if that matters.